# CMultifileUpload using Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii

The problem is that I can't get the CMultifileUpload instance in my controller/action, when I call this action using ajax

here is my code
in my view

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id' => 'form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false, 'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),)); ?>

    <div class="row">
    <?php
        $this -> widget('CMultiFileUpload', array('name' => 'wupload', 'accept' => 'zip', \
        'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
        'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
        'max' => 1
        ));

        echo CHtml::button('upload', array('onclick'=>'send()',));
        ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

here is my action in my controller

```
public function actionUpload(){
    $file = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('wupload');
    var_dump($file);
}
```

here is my script function

```
function send() {
    var data = $("#form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'upload',
        data : data,
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(data) {// if error occured
            alert("Error occured.please try again " + data);
        },

        dataType : 'html'
    });
}
```

now all what I receive after the alert shows is this

```
array(0){
}
```

I can't see my selected files, unlike if I used normal submit button, every thing worked correctly, I need someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does it return? public function actionUpload(){
  var_dump($_POST);
}

Comment: returns array(0){}, its what I print in alert, I mentioned this above by the way :)

Comment: sorry: var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: returns the same result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FormData object (NOTE: For IE it will only work in IE10+).

Lots of examples here, There's a jQuery one at the bottom.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects